# Find a Minecraft base with just an image and world seed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing on a Minecraft SMP and the enemy team posted an image of their base to flex on others.
I want to know if it's possible (and if it is, then how) to find their base coords if I have the world seed.

Server:
Paper 1.18 and an image of their base below.

[image]